# fgetcsv not reading csv file properly that is saved in linux system

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, csv

I'm trying to import some data through csv file into my database. The problem is that in the very beginning of the development I was using windows so my csv file was written on ms office. So while importing there it works fine. But switching to linux(UBUNTU) while saving the csv file it's not showing data as i want. I'm not getting any solution either.

This is the array which is generated by the csv that has been made by ms office on windows machine which works fine.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Student Name
        [1] => Student Roll
        [2] => Class
        [3] => Section
        [4] => Exam
        [5] => Subject
        [6] => Total Marks
        [7] => Grade
        [8] => Objective
        [9] => Subjective
        [10] => Practical
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Sample Name
        [1] => 123
        [2] => Nine
        [3] => A
        [4] => Mid Term
        [5] => Math
        [6] => 80
        [7] => A+
        [8] => 40
        [9] => 20
        [10] => 20
    )

)
```

But in linux my csv format is not working correctly. It's pushing all the data into one key & one element like below.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Student Name Student Roll    Class   Section Exam    Subject Total Marks Grade   Objective   Subjective  Practical
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Samp0le Name 123 Nine    A   Mid Term    Math    80  A+  40  20  20
    )

)
```

So my actual question is how can I get read of that?

This is my coding for the upper array generation:

```
$csv = array();
    //$file = fopen('myCSVFile.csv', 'r');
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
    while (($result = fgetcsv($fp)) !== false)
    {
        $csv[] = $result;
    }

    fclose($fp);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($csv);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Please help me I'm in very need actually ..

Comment: In your code you have no fopen() statement(as its commented out), thus fgetcsv($fp) will be null. Just in case anyone else notices that :)

Comment: @NeilMasters I've done this in my code. The upper array is generating perfectly. But the fact is windows & linux based csv files. Don't know what is the problem but want to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
$file = "FNAC_SPECTACLES.csv";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$row = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";","'")) !== FALSE) 
{
    if($row == 1)
    {
        // skip the first row   
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
    }
    $row++;
}
```

`fgetcsv()` in third argument in separator to you want to save in csv file. Ex: comma,semicolon or etc..

Comment: Thanks for the last one comment. It just fixes my whole thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have saved the file as - `separate values using tab` and not by `commas`.
Again `save as` the same file and select `commas` as `delimiter` for values separation and `double quotes` as values delimiter.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. You can see that the array is printing fine. On ms office based csv file it's working but on linux based csv file it's giving this problem the lower array.

Comment: As per your printed array, it seems that the field delimiter is been set to {tab} and not comma

Comment: I don't know if you've understood my problem or not. I need the same result means i need the second array seems like first array. second array is generated by a csv which is made in linux env.

Comment: Do one thing, open-with your csv file with gedit,sublime,etc. and check whether the values are separated with commas (,) or tab {tab}

Comment: I've done it. Thanks for the help. Your idea is also correct. I've just set the tab as separator of first line double quote works fine ..